# Count number of selected rows in uitableview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8, xcode6.3

What I actually want to do is to count the number of rows selected after selecting and deselecting the row. I get the total count but when I deselect the row I want to get count as how many other rows are still selected. My code is as follows

```
//countId = 0;
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        countId = countId + 1;
    }

    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

And then I have to pass the value of countId to another view and display it in a button. I know it is something small but I am not able to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: then you can decrement value of countId in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Comment: If I do that then how will I get total count?

Comment: then just fetch value at each time update i.e. didSelect and didDeselect and use it as you want

Comment: Can you give an example of how it is done. I am new at this so I don't have much idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask the table view for it's currently selected indexes, so if you only need to now how many, you can do:

```
[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows].count
```

**EDIT:**

To keep following the cells with `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` you can decrement `countId` like so:

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    countId = countId + 1;
}

else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    countId = countId - 1; 
}
```

Comment: Even when I am deselecting all the rows I get countId as 1

Comment: How do you deselect? I'm asking since calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath` does not call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` (and vice versa...)

Comment: Actually it is not deselecting. I just want to count rows selected on the basis of accessoryType. If it is checked then it should increment countId and if I uncheck it then it should decrement countId by 1

Comment: You are immediately deselecting the cell inside `didSelect...` in your code, the keep following the checkmarks you can just add `countId--;` in your `else` inside `didSelect`. Edited my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, Get the cell reference and change it's Accessory and then just reload your tableView and before that set countId = 0.

OR

Take one Mutable Array(selectedArray).

- Now in didSelecteRowAtIndexPath write below code

  if([selectedArray contains:indexpath.row]){
     [selectedArray removeObject:indexpath.row];
  }
  else{
     [selectedArray addObject:indexpath.row];
  }

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if([selectedArray contains:indexpath.row]){
     cell.AccessoryType = checkmark
}else{
     cell.AccessoryType = none
}
```

Hope this works for you.